# how to set color for each datapoint in chartjs-chart-treemap

Tags: angular, chart.js, treemap

I am producing a treemap with chartjs-chart-treemap v2.0 and chartsjs 3.6. I can't seem to find how to set the color of each box. I wouldexpect to find it here:

```
.....
 datasets: [{
      tree: Data.statsByState,
      key: 'area',
      groups: GROUPS,
      spacing: 1,
      borderWidth: 0.5,
      borderColor: 'rgba(200,200,200,1)',
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(220,230,220,0.3)',
      hoverBackgroundColor: 'rgba(220,230,220,0.5)',
      captions: {
        align: 'center',
        display: true,
        color: 'red',
        font: {
          size: 14,
        },
        hoverFont: {
          size: 16,
          weight: 'bold'
        },
        padding: 5
      }
    }]
```

Each datapoint value is handled in 'key' and 'groups', I would expect a similar property in datasets. Would appreciate any help on how to set the colors.

Comment: So do you want to set different color for each section of treemap ?

Comment: @GRD yup....each section represents a product ....I want each product to have a different color.

Comment: not quite... the actual code is giving an error with chart.helpers.color.. " property 'helpers' doesn't exist on typeof Chart". In addition I need to control the actual colors... the stackblitz example did work but a can't control the colors.... some are indistinguishable.

Comment: Can you explain more what indistinguishable mean to you ?

Comment: @grd Ok.... visually distinct... So I found the dataset index (ctx. raw. _data._idx) with this I can create my own array of distinct colors and use this index to assign a distinct color to each datapoint.... I will post as a possible answer for some.

Answer (score 1):

To control the colors assigned to each rectangle (datapoint) in the treemap. The index for the dataset array is buried in ctx.raw._data._idx. So you can create your own array of colors and assign each datapoint a specific color with:

```
  datasets.backgroundColor: (ctx)=>this.getColor(ctx)
```

in getColor

```
   getColor(ctx) { 
   const colors = [arrray of colors];
   if (ctx.type==='data') {
      return colors[ctx.raw._data._idx];  
   }
  else return 'transparent';
}
```